# android database larger than 1mb on assets folder

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have this db that is around 7MB and when I first started developing apps in 2014 I read that I should split the db in 1mb parts and put it on assets folder like so:
01.db
02.db
03.db
...
07.db

And on my db helper class I had

```
private void copyDataBase(File DBFile) throws IOException
    {
        AssetManager am = myContext.getAssets();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DBFile);
        DBFile.createNewFile();
        byte []b = new byte[1024];
        int i, r;
        String []Files = am.list("");
        Arrays.sort(Files);
        for(i=1;i<15;i++) //I have definitely less than 10 files; you might have more
        {
            String fn = String.format("0%d.db", i);
            System.out.println(fn);
            if(Arrays.binarySearch(Files, fn) < 0) //No such file in assets - time to quit the loop
                break;
            InputStream is = am.open(fn);
            while((r = is.read(b)) != -1)
                os.write(b, 0, r);
            is.close();
        }
        os.close();
    }
```

Is this piece of code still relevant? Here is my full db helper class, any of you guys have an updated version of it?
**DatabaseHelper.class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

//public static String PACKAGE_NAME
//PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
//The Androids default system path of your application database.
//private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"+PACKAGE_NAME+"/databases/";
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_NAME = "fulldb6";//name of your Database
//File DBFile                 = new File(DB_PATH, DB_NAME);
File DBFile;



/**
  * Constructor
  * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
  * @param context
  */

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(this.DB_NAME).getPath();;
    DBFile  = myContext.getDatabasePath(this.DB_NAME);

    //System.out.println(DBFile.getPath());
}

/**
  * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
  * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkIfDataBaseExists();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    } else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase(DBFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }


}

/**
  * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
  * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
  */
private boolean checkIfDataBaseExists(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        checkDB       = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch(SQLiteException e){


    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}



private void copyDataBase(File DBFile) throws IOException
{
    AssetManager am = myContext.getAssets();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DBFile);
    DBFile.createNewFile();
    byte []b = new byte[1024];
    int i, r;
    String []Files = am.list("");
    Arrays.sort(Files);
    for(i=1;i<15;i++) //I have definitely less than 10 files; you might have more
    {
        String fn = String.format("0%d.db", i);
        System.out.println(fn);
        if(Arrays.binarySearch(Files, fn) < 0) //No such file in assets - time to quit the loop
            break;
        InputStream is = am.open(fn);
        while((r = is.read(b)) != -1)
            os.write(b, 0, r);
        is.close();
    }
    os.close();
}


public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH ;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Also does anyone know if hardcoding the db_path to /data/data/com.packagename/databases cause any crashes? In devices with no memory and perhaps db is stored on sd card? Many people reported crashes or not working app, which I could not replicate on my device and android emulators.

Should I make a check that if there is no memory to install db in sdcard?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this piece of code still relevant?

It will result in failures for Android 9+ as the getReadableDatabase will result in the -wal and -shm files being created (WAL is turned on by default in Android 9+) these being marked as being owned by the new database. New database gets overwritten but the -wal and -shm files remain. Copy works but when the database is opened via SQliteOpenHelper the error due to the -shm and -wal files existing results in the a usable database which is empty i.e. the data has been wiped and typically the App will then crash with a table not found.

The only reason, I suspect, that the use of the getReadableDatabase or (getWritableDatabase no difference unless there's a disaster as such) has been historicaly used is that someone found that it got around the OpenError ENOENT when it wasn't used. What the get???Database does as part of the long and winding process of opening the database is create the databases directory if it doesn't exist.

Why the obvious use of **mkdirs** was not used I have no idea.

The efficient way of checking and preparing for the database file copy from the assets is to check to see if the database file exists (if it does then no need to copy from the assets), if it doesn't exist then check the File's parentFile (the databases folder) to see if it exists. If it doesn't exists then do a **mkdirs** on the parentfile then copy the file.

- No needless open of the database file,
- no generation of -wal and -swm file,
- no underlying processing to create the database file, the -shm file and the -wal file simply for them to be discarded.
  -no vanishing table tricks.

> /data/data/com.packagename/databases

There have been many issues raised due to issues (primarily typos). However, THERE IS NO NEED TO HARD CODE. Use the **Context**'s **getDatabasePath(dbname)** method to return the path. The only hard code (and that should be 1 place as constant) is the database name (DB_NAME in your case).

> So I have this db that is around 7MB and when I first started developing apps in 2014 I read that I should split the db in 1mb parts and put it on assets folder like so: 01.db 02.db 03.db ... 07.db

I don't think this limitation remains. I believe assets can be part of the 100mb for the APK but larger data can be handled with expansion APK's.